# Alternatives to UML Tools closer to languages?

Tags: java, .net, code-generation, uml

Found this one
http://www.kite9.com/content/adl-new-visual-language-part-2 (presentation here http://www.kite9.com/content/muddle-uml) not cheap :(

Any others that can also do same kind of thing (reverse enginier, code generation from code directly) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you are open to try something different, take a look at [Umple](http://cruise.site.uottawa.ca/umple/) It merges the concepts of programming and modeling by adding modeling abstractions directly into programming languages .

Answer (score 1):

Object Role Modeling? http://www.orm.net/ it is for datamodeling, but it is way more expressive than the tipica E-R diagrams and it has way to be converted to and back from logical predicates

Comment: It's still very far from code there's no tool that can reverse or generate doc to it from code.